# Can't connect to SQL Server 2005 after installing SQL Server 7

Tags: sql-server, service, connect

Yes I know i's old software...here's the story.

SQL Server 2005 installed and been happy for years. New client has a SQL Server 7 database I need to connect to remotely - SQL Server 2005 client tools won't connect to it. Got client's Sql Server 7 disk and installed - works fine to connect to client's database remotely - but now I can't start my local SQL Server 2005 database service - in SQL Server configuration manager the service is stopped - when I try and start it it just says it failed and to check the event log...

In the event log it reports:
 The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service was successfully sent a start control.
immediately followed by
The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service entered the stopped state.

Under Application it reports:

17050 :
initerrlog: Could not open error log file 'C:\MSSQL7\log\ERRORLOG'. Operating system error = 5(Access is denied.)

Which to my inexperienced eyes tells me it's trying to do something with SQL Server 7 which implies the installation of SQL Server 7 has messed with my SQL Server 2005 installation...I suppose reinstalling SQL Server 2005 is the answer but it's Saturday and all CDs/DVDss at the office....suggestions anyone?

Thanks

Ray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think you are going to need to repair your installation.  Server software is designed to handle installing newer versions (usually) in conjunction with older versions.  However, older versions don't know how to install and not break newer versions (since they didn't exist when the installer was created).  It looks like SQL 7 corrupted your SQL 2005 installation.  Hopefully a repair should be all you need.  If you have access to MSDN, you could download the ISOs.  Otherwise, you may be stuck making an office run.